# How to show qwerty keyboard when edittext is focused

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, textinput

How to show qwerty keyboard when edittext is focused? 
Currently this keyboard is opening:
[image]

but I want to open this type of keyboard:

[image]

**It happens when phone keyboard is set in settings and in Samsung devices**

My layout.xml:

```
<com.text.view.DashedEditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="20dip"
    android:inputType="text" />
```

How to do it? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: post the layout xml. i guess you are setting the inputtype of edittext to number

Comment: Ok, but setting it to "text" doesn't work.

Comment: are you setting a keylistener or setting inputtype programmatically?

Comment: I edited my post. I'm not setting keylistener nor inputtype programmatically.

Comment: okay.. i guess you are using emulator. Long press the inputText and change  the keyboard to Android Keyboard. For some stupid reason google starts emulator with japanese keyboard

Comment: You misunderstood me :P. It's not a language problem. I want to open "full qwerty keyboard" instead of "phone keyboard".

Comment: i am not asking you to change the language. change the keyboard. you are using Pinyin IME not the Android keyboard

Comment: Ignoring current keyboard settings/languages/etc. when edittext is focused I want full qwerty keyboard (http://i.stack.imgur.com/ueeiI.jpg ) to be opened.

Comment: That is not possible. What kind of keyboard shows up is entirely based on which keyboard you are using.